# Get revisor detail using SearchQueryData

Tags: core-service

I want to display the components modified by particular user using core service for which I m using SearchQueryData filter. I m getting the list of modified components but details of user who last modified the component is missing. For getting these details I m iterating through each item and getting the Version history but doing this way degrades the performance.

Here is the code:

```
            //search query 
            SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData();
            filter.ModifiedAfter = fromDate;
            filter.ModifiedBefore = toDate;
            filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[]
            {
                ItemType.Component,
                ItemType.ComponentTemplate,
                ItemType.Page,
                ItemType.PageTemplate,
                ItemType.Publication,
                ItemType.Schema
            };

            filter.BlueprintStatus = SearchBlueprintStatus.Unspecified;
            filter.SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData { Title = publicationId };

            //returns the list of items changed by date
            IdentifiableObjectData[] dataModified = client.GetSearchResults(filter);
            List<IdentifiableObjectData> modifiedData_User = new List<IdentifiableObjectData>();

            //iterate through each item and get the details of the user who modified this item
            foreach (var d in dataModified)
            {
                VersionsFilterData versionsFilter = new VersionsFilterData();
                versionsFilter.IncludeRevisorDescriptionColumn = true;
                IdentifiableObjectData versionList = client.GetList(d.Id, versionsFilter).Last();
                var versionInfo = (FullVersionInfo)versionList.VersionInfo;
                LinkToUserData revisor = versionInfo.Revisor;
                if (revisor.Title.ToLower() == username.ToLower())
                    modifiedData_User.Add(d);
            }
```

1) Can I get the details of user who modified the component using SearchQueryDataFilter so that I dont have to iterate through the result.
2) Is there any better way through which this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `SearchQueryData.Author` Property used to set the author to search for. Did you try that? I can't test it running the code now, so can't confirm.

**Update**: using `SearchQueryData.Author` Property, The results will return items created by the specified author. So I guess you are doing it rightly looping over the results.